# VB.NET - Change form size by screen resolution:

Tags: vb.net, resize, resolution

I'm presuming the answers very simple, but here's the issue, my option menu has two parts, normal settings and advanced settings, the advanced settings are accessed by pressing the advance button, fairly basic. This will make the form bigger unveiling the further settings, but the only problem I have is making a form bigger on different resolution does not make it bigger by the same factor - to put what i saying into context, if i increase the size of my form on a standard 1080p monitor, then run my program on a laptop resolution of 1366 by 768, the form will be much smaller than what i got it to draw on the 1080p resolution screen.

Heres the code I'm using to increase the form size:

```
Private Sub Advance_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Advance_btn.Click
    If advanced = 0 Then
        Me.Size = New Drawing.Size(262, 198) ' will increase form size
        Advance_btn.Text = "<" ' text for button changes to know i have pressed the button - (to '<')
        advanced = 1
    ElseIf advanced = 1 Then
        Me.Size = New Size(262, 85) ' will decrease form size
        Advance_btn.Text = ">" ' text for button changes to know i have pressed the button - (to '>')
        advanced = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

The form is also without borders, if that makes somewhat a difference, thanks.

Comment: Getting screen dimensions is pretty straight-forward using Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.[Width/Height], how much you scale the form size in relation to those bounds is up to you

Answer (score -1):

```
        Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
        Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width * 0.6
```

In this example I use for years, the width is set to 60% of the screen width. This is in an IF statement, where I check if the user has a 4K monitor, if not, a full-screen mode is set at application start-up. You can, perpahs, do a similar thing with your drawing area.

Comment: This code is wrong. It hard-codes the assumption that the form is being displayed on the primary screen, which is not necessarily true. Consider multiple-monitor systems.

Comment: I do have a multiple-monitor system, in fact all our computers have two monitors. Some have 4K as a primary monitors, other are all full-HD. So I know what you mean, but in reality there's a zero problem. Testedy by years.

Comment: The code cannot work in that scenario. It uses the `PrimaryScreen` object. If your secondary screen uses a different resolution from the primary screen, or the form is not on the primary screen, then you have set the wrong dimensions.

Comment: Yet it does. And for all other who suggested this solution in past. However, if you get into trouble, you can possibly get the screen you need using Screen.FromControl(Me).